# Autofocus for input, when there is iframe on page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, autofocus

I use react and redux in project. I have input and iframe on page. In component function "componentDidMount" I wrote such code (it's just an example):

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.input.focus();
}
```

Autofocus doesn't work if there is iframe on page, but if I remove iframe, autofocus will work. What could be the problem?

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: What's inside your iframe? If you put in this iframe a simple custom HTML it is working?
It's possible that this iframe handle some sort of focus too.

Comment: Autofocus also doesn't work with empty <iframe></iframe>

Comment: Can you show more code? Will be nice to see your components.